# Traces of Matrix as a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $W$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices such that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 0$. Is $W$ a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the vector space of all complex $n \times n$ matrices.

I know that we need to check that we have closure under addition and scalar multiplication. My issue with this question is that I am having trouble approaching the proof that both of these two rules are satisfied. More specifically, what do I add together to show that these are closed? How do I show that $\operatorname{tr}(A)+\operatorname{tr}(B)=\operatorname{tr}(A+B)$.

Comment: We have not used summation notation for anything that we have covered in the class. Is it possible to prove this without that notation?

Answer (score 1):

The operator $\operatorname{tr}$ is a linear operator and $\ker \operatorname{tr}$ is a linear subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Recall that trace is just the sum of the diagonals.

Hence you just have to answer the following question

- Is sum of (sum of diagonal of $A$ and sum of diagonal of $B$) equal to  the sum of diagonal of $A+B$?
- Is the sum of diagonal of $kA$ equal to $k$ times the sum of diagonal of $A$?

Once you can answer the two questions above, proving closure should be manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $0 \in W$, because $tr(0) = 0$. As for the other two properties, suppose $A,B \in W$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$. Now,

$$
tr(\alpha \cdot A + \beta \cdot B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha \cdot A + \beta \cdot B)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha \cdot a_{ii} + \beta \cdot b_{ii} = \\
\alpha \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii} + \beta \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{ii} =  \alpha \cdot tr(A) + \beta \cdot tr(B) = 0
$$

so in fact $\alpha \cdot A + \beta \cdot B \in W$ and $W$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the set of $n \times n$ matrices with $0$ trace is closed under addition. This means that, given two arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(B) = 0$, that $\operatorname{tr}(A + B) = 0$. As you've correctly identified, this is to do with the rule, $\operatorname{tr}(A + B) = \operatorname{tr}(A) + \operatorname{tr}(B)$.

How do you show it? It's pretty straight forward, once you get a handle on the notation. It's conventional to denote the entry of $A$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column by $(A)_{ij}$. The trace is the sum of the diagonal elements, hence
$$\operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (A)_{ii}.$$
Recall also the definition of the sum of matrices. We have,
$$(A + B)_{ij} = (A)_{ij} + (B)_{ij}.$$
Putting this together, we get
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}(A + B) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n (A + B)_{ii} \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n ((A)_{ii} + (B)_{ii}) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (A)_{ii} + \sum_{i = 1}^n (B)_{ii} \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(A) + \operatorname{tr}(B).
\end{align*}
There's nothing hidden, fancy, or complicated here, except possibly the notation. Hopefully, you can finish the proof that $\operatorname{tr}$ is a linear function, that is $\operatorname{tr}(\alpha A) = \alpha \operatorname{tr}(A)$. It's proven in much the same way, and should give you closure under scalar multiplication.